Obscure sci-fi movie that featured synthetic human hearts that need regular replacement
This seemingly obscure film probably from late 80s to late 90s  features a future society where synthetic heart replacements are common, and people must renew them periodically, especially if they experience failures. The plot involves a male protagonist who also has this synthetic heart inside him who navigates this futuristic healthcare system, while a villain's fate ultimately hinges on the failure to replace his synthetic heart in time.
I also remember there is a scene where the male protagonist talks to his (love interest) or girl friend in a roof-less car where the girl shows these synthetic heart "options" to get or buy in a touch screen device.
This is not repo men or robo cop. Even AI seem to struggle to find this obscure movie. It's probably a TV movie. I remember it shown on Cinemax probably in 2006-07

Was it definitely a movie or maybe an episode of a sci-fi anthology series?

ArlettaS  I sure remember it as a movie. I've seen it shown in the HBO subchannel Cinemax around 2006 or 2007

Is this close?

eyoung100 not even close.
